# Declare Sammy js setup using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript, sammy.js

I just running through the KnockOut.js tutorial but replacing the JS code with TS. I've got stuck on the following code when adding SammyJS. Can anybody advise how the Sammy function code in TS?

```
function WebmailViewModel() {
// Data
var self = this;
self.folders = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
self.chosenFolderId = ko.observable();
self.chosenFolderData = ko.observable();
self.chosenMailData = ko.observable();

// Behaviours    
self.goToFolder = function(folder) { location.hash = folder };
self.goToMail = function(mail) { location.hash = mail.folder + '/' + mail.id };

// Client-side routes    
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#:folder', function() {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenMailData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { folder: this.params.folder }, self.chosenFolderData);
    });

    this.get('#:folder/:mailId', function() {
        self.chosenFolderId(this.params.folder);
        self.chosenFolderData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { mailId: this.params.mailId }, self.chosenMailData);
    });

    this.get('', function() { this.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox') });
}).run();    
};

ko.applyBindings(new WebmailViewModel());
```

The tutorial I am following is here http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail

Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm a future visitor who would be very helped by this!  I suggest the question should be considered in light of what the author emphasized: "Can anybody advise how the Sammy function code in TS?"

Comment: I also would like an answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you can potentially leverage a TypeScript definition file that describes Sammy here https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sammyjs/sammyjs.d.ts This should have enough of the sammy api for you to continue your tutorial.

Download the definition file and reference with a special comment similar to below.

```
///<reference path="sammyjs/sammyjs.d.ts" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this did cause me enough pain to warrant a recommendation for the future visitors.

I have re-written the example code above in TypeScript.

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/Sammy/Sammy.d.ts" />
import sammy = require("sammy");
class WebmailViewModel
{
    // Data
    public folders: Array<string> = ['Inbox', 'Archive', 'Sent', 'Spam'];
    public chosenFolderId: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();
    public chosenFolderData: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();
    public chosenMailData: KnockoutObservable<any> = ko.observable();

    // Behaviours    
    public goToFolder = function (folder) { window.location.hash = folder };
    public goToMail = function (mail) { window.location.hash = mail.folder + '/' + mail.id };

    // Client-side routes    
    public SammyApp: sammy.Application =
    Sammy().get('#:folder', context =>
    {
        this.chosenFolderId(context.params.folder);
        this.chosenMailData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { folder: context.params.folder }, this.chosenFolderData);
    }).get('#:folder/:mailId', context =>
    {
        this.chosenFolderId(context.params.folder);
        this.chosenFolderData(null);
        $.get("/mail", { mailId: context.params.mailId }, this.chosenMailData);
    }).get('', context =>
    {
        context.app.runRoute('get', '#Inbox');
    }).run();
};
```

Then, in $(document).ready()

```
var viewModel = new WebmailViewModel;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Many thanks to @Vladimir whose answer [stack overflow question 19395335](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395335/declare-routes-in-sammy-js-in-typescript)
lead me to the solution.

Cheers.